# Center the loader in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, css-animations

I am trying to center this loader which I got from https://cssloaders.github.io/ in the middle of the page with a dark background.

I am currently getting some weird layout and was not sure how to do the same.

This is the .css file

```
.bg {
    background-color: black;
    display: table;
    max-height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.loader {
    width: 48px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 15% 15% 35% 35%;
  }
  .loader::after {
    content: '';  
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    left: 45px;
    top: 8px;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    width: 16px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  }
  .loader::before {
    content: '';  
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    top: -15px;
    left: 11px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: animloader 1s ease infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes animloader {
      0% {
    box-shadow: 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 12px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 20px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
      50% {
    box-shadow: 2px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 12px -3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 20px -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  }
      100% {
    box-shadow: 2px -8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 12px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 20px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
    }
```

The js file

```
import React from 'react'
import './styles.css'

const SpinnerComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div class="bg">
        <span class="loader"></span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SpinnerComponent
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes are in `.loader` and in `.bg`:

```css
.bg {
    background-color: black;
    
    max-height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.loader {
    width: 48px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 15% 15% 35% 35%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  }
  .loader::after {
    content: '';  
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    left: 45px;
    top: 8px;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    width: 16px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  }
  .loader::before {
    content: '';  
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    top: -15px;
    left: 11px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: animloader 1s ease infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes animloader {
      0% {
    box-shadow: 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 12px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 20px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
      50% {
    box-shadow: 2px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 12px -3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 20px -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  }
      100% {
    box-shadow: 2px -8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 12px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 20px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
    }
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    <span class="loader"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to put the loader span inside a container div and using flexbox bring the loader to the center of the page.

here is the code to achieve it.

```css
.loader {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 5px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FF3D00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: rotation 1s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes rotation {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    } 

.wrapper{
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="loader"></span>  
</div>
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/anubhavmunjaal/pen/YzjZzxP